# How to query Room database for LiveData<String> while passing a variable

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

When I hard code the variable the query works:

From the Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT amount FROM note_table WHERE item = 'Apple'")
    LiveData<String> getAmount();
```

but when I try to pass a variable it doesn't.

```
 @Query("SELECT amount FROM note_table WHERE item = :items")
    LiveData<String> getAmountwithItem(String items);
```

From the ViewModel:

```
private final LiveData<String> NoteAmount, NoteAmountwithItem;

NoteAmount = repository.getAmount();
NoteAmountwithItem = repository.getNoteAmountwithItem();

 LiveData<String> getAmount() {
        return NoteAmount;
    }

 LiveData<String> getNoteAmountwithItem() {
        return NoteAmountwithItem;
    }
```

From the Repository:

```
private final LiveData<String> NoteAmount, NoteAmountwithItem;

NoteAmount = noteDao.getAmount();
NoteAmountwithItem = noteDao.getAmountwithItem();

LiveData<String> getAmount() {
        return NoteAmount;
    }

LiveData<String> getNoteAmountwithItem() {
        return NoteAmountwithItem;
    }
```

From MainActivity.java

```
noteViewModel.getAmount().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String queryAmount) {
                if(queryAmount != null){
                    updateamount = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(queryAmount) + 1);
                    testTextView.setText("Amount: " + updateamount);
                }else{
                    updateamount = "1";
                }
            }
        });
```

This gives me the amount of Apples in queryAmount but I have different fruits and want to pass the fruit as a variable and get the amount of specific fruits.

Comment: did you pass a String to `noteDao.getAmountwithItem("Apple");`?

Comment: If I add "Apple" to this statement in the Reposity: NoteAmountwithItem = noteDao.getAmountwithItem("Apple"); and use getAmountwithItem instead of getAmount from the MainActivity it works but how do I pass the String from the Main Activity?

Comment: Please check the answer .. feel free to contact back if something not clear

Comment: On the Repository and ViewModel the `NoteAmountwithItem = noteDao.getAmountwithItem();` line wants an argument. I placed "" but does that override the variable I set on the MainActivity in the `noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem(items).observe` line?

Comment: You an remove these lines .. I already used it in the body of the methods in the answer

Comment: I've got everything set up correctly now and it seems to work sometimes but other times comes back null when it shouldn't be. Am I going about this wrong? Is there a better way to simply retrieve the amount value without observe? I tired `appleamount = noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem("Apple").getValue();` and `appleamount = noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem("Apple").toString();` but neither worked.

Comment: This won't work as `LiveData` works implicitly in a background thread, so you must use the observer pattern

Comment: So I pick up a fruit and cycle through `noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem(fruit).observe` If the fruit was an apple and I already have 2 apples `(queryAmount)` then add +1 and further update the Note. Then I pick up an Orange, it works. Then another Apple and `queryAmount` is null this time. `queryAmount` just seems to go null randomly for each fruit through the process.

Comment: I encourage you to store them as integer instead of String.. it will be more efficient and less error-prone

Comment: if you'd provide a sample app on github in order to allow reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you Zain, I will upload to github. I have also converted to Integer as you suggested. What is the proper way to remove the `noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem(fruit).observe` I tired `noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem(fruit).removeObserver(this);` inside the  `onChanged`

Comment: Not sure if this will work within `onChanged`.. but you can create an instance variable for the observer ... and then use `noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem(fruit).removeObserver(myObserver);` I am sure this will work

Comment: Zain, here is the [Github Link](https://github.com/MDodd423/FruitMVVM) Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Zain, I know we have gotten outside the scope of the question but I was wanting to follow-up and check if you had taken a look at the github? Thanks

Comment: Sorry if that was late.. I just couldn't build up the project on android studio .. turns out that you uploaded the files on github not the entire project ... if you are up now we can discuss it ... feel free to contact back to discuss it with a chat

Comment: Now works well for me, not sure how to start a chat, though.

Comment: Now which files that I can check in your code

Comment: The MainActivity.java should update the amount of fruit by 1 when the get fruit button is pressed but the amount goes null or copies the amount of a different fruit.

Comment: Can you change in NoteDao `@Query("SELECT amount FROM note_table WHERE item LIKE :items")
    LiveData<Integer> getAmountwithItem(String items);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227661/discussion-between-zain-and-mdodd423).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a String argument to `getAmountwithItem()` from activity all the way down to the `DAO` interface

In Dao (Keep it the same as yours):

```
@Query("SELECT amount FROM note_table WHERE item = :items")
LiveData<String> getAmountwithItem(String items);
```

In Repository:

```
LiveData<String> getNoteAmountwithItem(String item) {
    return noteDao.getAmountwithItem(item);
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
LiveData<String> getNoteAmountwithItem(String item) {
    return repository.getNoteAmountwithItem(item);
}
```

In Activity (pass the String you want to look for):

```
noteViewModel.getNoteAmountwithItem("Apple").observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String queryAmount) {
        if(queryAmount != null){
            updateamount = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(queryAmount) + 1);
            testTextView.setText("Amount: " + updateamount);
        }else{
            updateamount = "1";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question I asked. But, LiveData was not the proper solution to the problem I was trying to solve. @Zain helped me implement a Listener Interface that has worked great for the situation. Thank you.